# Firebase Android - send notification messages using POST requests without an App Server, but directly from the Android app

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to send push notification directly from an Android app by making POST requests directly to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send ? If so, can you please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read JavaScript, check the [simple-fcm-client example on react-native-fcm](https://github.com/tioback/react-native-fcm/tree/master/Examples/simple-fcm-client). Specifficaly, the `FirebaseClient.js` file

I'll post the code here for completeness, but you need to replace `token` with the destined device's registered token and FirebaseConstants.KEY with your API Web key from your Firebase console.

```
const API_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

class FirebaseClient {

  constructor() {
    this.sendData = this.sendData.bind(this);
    this.sendNotification = this.sendNotification.bind(this);
    this.sendNotificationWithData = this.sendNotificationWithData.bind(this);
  }

  sendNotification(token) {
    let body = {
        "to": token,
      "notification":{
            "title": "Simple FCM Client",
            "body": "This is a notification with only NOTIFICATION.",
            "sound": "default",
            "click_action": "fcm.ACTION.HELLO"
        },
        "priority": 10
    }

    this._send(JSON.stringify(body), "notification");
  }

  sendData(token) {
    let body = {
        "to": token,
      "data":{
            "title": "Simple FCM Client",
            "body": "This is a notification with only DATA.",
            "sound": "default",
            "click_action": "fcm.ACTION.HELLO",
            "remote": true
        },
        "priority": "normal"
    }

    this._send(JSON.stringify(body), "data");
  }

  sendNotificationWithData(token) {
    let body = {
      "to": token,
      "notification":{
            "title": "Simple FCM Client",
            "body": "This is a notification with NOTIFICATION and DATA (NOTIF).",
            "sound": "default",
            "click_action": "fcm.ACTION.HELLO"
        },
        "data":{
            "title": "Simple FCM Client",
            "body": "This is a notification with NOTIFICATION and DATA (DATA)",
            "click_action": "fcm.ACTION.HELLO",
            "remote": true
        },
        "priority": "high"
    }

    this._send(JSON.stringify(body), "notification-data");
  }

  _send(body, type) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": parseInt(body.length),
      "Authorization": "key=" + FirebaseConstants.KEY
    });

    fetch(API_URL, { method: "POST", headers, body })
        .then(response => console.log("Send " + type + " response", response))
        .catch(error => console.log("Error sending " + type, error));
  }

}
```

Comment: And whst I need to do with this file inside my Android app ?

Comment: This file is just to give you an idea, not to put it in the project. Android also has a fetch API, so it adapting the above code should be very straightforward.